# EF - Multiple Primary Keys Linking Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, foreign-key-relationship, multiple-tables

We need a solution to the following problem which makes sense an also follows best practices without making things to complicated.

We have 3 tables which need to be linked, **Sector**, **Location** and **Company**.

ie: A **Company** "Bobs B&B" is in **Sector** "Accommodation" which is in **Location** "New York".
For hotel groups we could have a single company in multiple sectors across multiple locations.

So we decided to simply create a "**CompanySectorLocation**" table which has 3 primary keys linking the 3 tables:

```
CompanySectorLocation
    CompanyID (PK FK)
    SectorID (PK FK)
    LocationID (PK FK)
```

The curved ball here is that the Location is not required.

ie: "Protea Hotels" is active in the "Accomodation" sector leaving the location as *NULL*.

My developer is very much against having a table that allows for a ***NULL FK***.  His suggestion is to create another table called **CompanySector** which will deal with the links between **Company** and **Sector** where **Location** is not defined.

```
CompanySector
    CompanyID (PK FK)
    SectorID (PK FK)
```

My issue with this is that we will have to maintain 2 tables with effectively duplicate data in them.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, depending on your DBMS (SqlServer, Oracle, for example), you just can't have a composite key with a null value in any part of the composite key. (By the way, a table cannot have 3 PKs. I think you mean one composite PK based on 3 columns)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you need the 'linking' table in this case...

Comment: You cannot have multiple primary keys - do you mean a **compound** primary key (made up from multiple columns)?`

Comment: Apologies, i did mean a composite key with 3 parts. My developer wants the linking table to prevent the need for `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` clauses which may over complicate future search queries.  This is just a small part of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate table.  I have nothing against NULL FK's (many people do), but having one table means you're going to have duplicate data anyway.  E.g. if Bob's B&B opens up a branch in California, you'll have duplicate entries in the table specifying the relationship between 'Bob's B&B' and 'Accommodation'.  Having a single table also means you'll have to include `DISTINCT` in any join on this table only involving the CompanyID and SectorID columns (which seems likely if LocationID is nullable).

Effectively you will have two many-to-many relationships:

```
(Company) <-> (Sector)
```

and

```
(Company/Sector) <-> (Location)
```

It makes sense to use two linking tables to model two different relationships.  If you need all 3 entries in one table (for convenience), you can always create an indexed view.

Comment: We gonna go on this one. It makes sense. The only problem is that EF (Code First) creates your joining tables for you.  So the `CompanySector` table would only be created at run time which made referencing it from `Locations` difficult.  But simply fixed, we created the `CompanySector` table manually. If we want the `Sectors` that a `Company` runs in we simply use `Company.CompanySector.Sectors`.  Thanks for your help!